# Comparing string in mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Here is a trigger i created and i want to compare new.utype with employee as given below but dont know the actual way to compare it in mysql .. how can i achieve this and also please tell if condition syntax is correct or not

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER insdetail_tomaster
AFTER INSERT ON tempdetail
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF(new.utype =='employee') THEN
INSERT INTO master_employee values(new.field1,new.filed2);
ELSE 
INSERT INTO master_manager values(new.field1,new.fiel2);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please help me is there any one here

Comment: Looks ok, except for new.filed2 should be new.field2 and new is normally written NEW. What's the exact problem you are facing? Does the trigger work as expected?

Comment: thanks  the problem is over i used strcmp function for comparing

Answer (score 2):

Use "like" key word as below

```
IF new.utype like 'employee'
```

Entire trigger looks like this

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER insdetail_tomaster
AFTER INSERT ON tempdetail
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF new.utype like 'employee'  THEN
INSERT INTO master_employee values(new.field1,new.filed2);
ELSE 
INSERT INTO master_manager values(new.field1,new.fiel2);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

I assumed trigger you wrote other than the string comparison is correct
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single `=` instead of `==`

```
IF new.utype = 'employee'
```

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER insdetail_tomaster
AFTER INSERT ON tempdetail
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF new.utype = 'employee' THEN
    INSERT INTO master_employee values(new.field1,new.filed2);
  ELSE 
    INSERT INTO master_manager values(new.field1,new.fiel2);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

You can also use `<>` for comparing not equal value.

```
IF new.utype <> 'employee'
```

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER insdetail_tomaster
AFTER INSERT ON tempdetail
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF new.utype <> 'employee' THEN
    INSERT INTO master_employee values(new.field1,new.filed2);
  ELSE 
    INSERT INTO master_manager values(new.field1,new.fiel2);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```